# Does it cost the subscriber additional money send/respond to short code numbers

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I have a shortcode setup on my Marketing Cloud instance, I would like to know whether recipients of my SMS messages incur additional costs to respond back to those messages?

Comment: Depends on the carrier and the plan

Comment: Outside of the MC world, from what I remember shortcode costs can either be absorbed by the recipient or charged to the sender. Can anyone confirm how MC does this? Can this be specified by MC?

Comment: Which country was the short code provisioned for?